# Adding function per row in data frame into a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically im trying to use a user defined function to calculate values in a row in each dataframe and presenting them to a new column ABCD.

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [10,20,30,40,50], 'C': 
[5,5,5,5,5], 'D' : [2,2,2,2,2]})
print(df)


   A   B  C  D  E(Desired)
0  1  10  5  2
1  2  20  5  2
2  3  30  5  2
3  4  40  5  2
4  5  50  5  2

def functionx(A,B,C,D):
    print( A * B + C / D)



dfx['ABCD'] = functionX
```

i tried using functionX but it does not work. How do i pass the function correctly through each row and produce a column E which is the result?

Comment: You don't need a function. You can directly apply the formula on the columns with `dfx["E"] =  dfx.A * dfx.B + dfx.C / dfx.D`. However, you want to apply a specific function row per row, have a look at [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Answer (score 2):

Add a new column in DataFrame with values based on other columns

You can achieve that by directly performing the required operation on the desired column element-wise:

```
import pandas as pd

dfx = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [10,20,30,40,50], 'C':
[5,5,5,5,5], 'D' : [2,2,2,2,2]})
print(dfx)

dfx['E'] =  dfx['A'] * dfx['B'] + dfx['C'] / dfx['D']
print(dfx)
```

output:

```
   A   B  C  D      E
0  1  10  5  2   12.5
1  2  20  5  2   42.5
2  3  30  5  2   92.5
3  4  40  5  2  162.5
4  5  50  5  2  252.5
```

or you can use `DataFrame.apply()` function to achieve this task:

```
dfx['E'] = dfx.apply(lambda row: row.A * row.B + row.C / row.D, axis = 1)
```

NOTE:

> **Apply a function along an axis(columns or rows) of the DataFrame:**
>
> Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is
>   either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the DataFrame’s columns
>   (axis=1). By default (result_type=None), the final return type is
>   inferred from the return type of the applied function. Otherwise, it
>   depends on the result_type argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use unpacking with `pandas.DataFrame.apply` on `axis=1`:

```
dfx['E'] = dfx.apply(lambda x: functionx(*x), 1)
print(dfx)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  C  D      E
0  1  10  5  2   12.5
1  2  20  5  2   42.5
2  3  30  5  2   92.5
3  4  40  5  2  162.5
4  5  50  5  2  252.5
```

Comment: what does the `*` inside the function do?

Comment: @mohanys it _unpacks_ the iterable, so that one doesn't have to do `functionx(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])`.

Comment: oh! was not aware of that, that for the info

Comment: @mohanys The document for [pep-0448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) is about the unpacking. Might be helpful for ya :)